# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'writer'

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to execute this following program to read csv file in sublime text2 gets error message "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'writer'"
Any Solution.

```
import sys
import csv
def readcsv():
  f = open("F://xyz.csv",'r')
  readerr=csv.reader(f)
  for row in readerr():
      print row
  f.close()
readcsv()
```

FULL ERROR MESSAGE

> The current working directory is F:\ Traceback (most recent call
>   last):  File "F:\readfiles.py", line 12, in     readcsv()
>   File "F:\readfiles.py", line 7, in readcsv    readerr=csv.reader(f)
>        AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'reader'
>        [Finished in 1.4s with exit code 1]

Comment: So does this file actually exist? is `f` actually a valid file object?

Comment: Sorry the error is :AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'reader'

Comment: You obviously have another module named `csv` in your `sys.path` - to know which one, just add a `print csv` line just after the `import csv` one.

Comment: Well aside from your error this line looks iffy: `for row in readerr():` shouldn't it be `for row in readerr:`?

Comment: @EdChum .. True but the error is on the line before that.

Answer (score 4):

Debugging steps:-

Ideally `csv` should have `reader` module. My best guess is you have some other module named `csv` which is being imported. Can you try the following on python console:-'

```
>>>import csv
>>>dir(csv)
```

If you do not find the `reader`, `writer` etc. modules, chances are you are importing a wrong module with same name. Now try `>>>csv.__file__`, Rename this file and follow previous step once again.

In general your code could look pythonic the following way:-

```
with open('csvfile.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
     rows = csv.reader(csvfile)
     for row in rows:
         print row
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is slightly off.

for row in readerr():

The parenthesis is function syntax.
The command should only be acting on an object.

If you change that line to this, it will work
for row in reader:

Comment: OOPS  , the revised syntax did not make it into the answer                          for row in readerr:

Answer (score 0):

you must have named the file as csv.py, renaming it would troubleshoot the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error and the reason was my file name was also called 'csv.py'
Try changing it to something else and try again. Should work !! :)